# difference between firm and organization?

Tags: meaning

Recently during a conversation I was corrected by one of the clients when I used the word 'firm' to refer to his...firm/organization/company which is basically an international bank.

The sentence was : " has mr. X left the firm?"

He corrected me : " Organization."

until now I was using these words interchangeably...
can somebody put some light on the differences between the two and their usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all organizations are firms. For example a book-lovers' club is an organization but not a firm.  "Firm" is just a synonym for "company"--a business enterprise. So you were right to call his bank a firm. He was also right to call it an organization, but was wrong to think that his organization wasn't a firm. But the two terms aren't interchangeable, as you believed.

Comment: The correction was probably due to the association of "firms" with legal firms. In the US we rarely refer to banks as "firms".

Answer (score 1):

An organization is much wider term. It could refer to business enterprise as well as to non-business, such as a charity, a social club among others. It could also be governmental versus the NGO's. Finally, a business entity -one type of organizations as referred above- could be a company or a firm. From my career life and experience, a firm is referred to professional bureaus offering special type of services, such as legal consultancy, accounting & audit services, management & financial advisory etc.

Answer (score 0):

Firm; (is related to the partnership)sole proprietorship. 
Organization "(related to the non profit  organization and it is for large scale

Answer (score -1):

A firm makes up an organization
  A firm is said to b an inter related part of an organization that works hand in hand to achieve the goal of d organization (Goal of an organization is profit making).

Comment: You need to edit your post to correct typos--and also, ELU wants answers that show definitions and their source and explain why this answers the poster's question.